# echo out mysql_real_escaped quotes cuts off strings after quote or double quote

Tags: php, mysql, quotes, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm experiencing this odd, yet annoying syntax problem for browsers. By coding the way below, I lose all the strings after the special character: `"`

```
    echo '<td><input type=text style=width:100px name=itembrand value="' . $itembrand . ' " </td>';
    echo '<td><input type=text style=width:150px name=itemname value="' . $itemname . '" </td>';
    echo '<td><input type=text style=width:150 name=serialnr value="' . $serialnr . '" </td>';
    echo '<td><input type=text style=width:150px name=addinfo value="' . $addinfo . '" </td><td>';
```

If I code the other way around, I lose everything after the `'`:

```
    echo "<td><input type=text style=width:37px name=code value='" . $code ."' </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text style=width:100px name=itembrand value='" . $itembrand . "' </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text style=width:150px name=itemname value='" . $itemname . "' </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text style=width:150 name=serialnr value='" . $serialnr . "' </td>";
    echo "<td><input type=text style=width:150px name=addinfo value='" . $addinfo . "' </td><td>";
```

What is the correct syntax, to echo out database items even with `'` and `"` together with the strings after it?

Note:
 I'm using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` and the database entry is right, so this must be something with the syntax.

Comment: You are missing closing tags for your input elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I used `htmlspecialchars()` to get this right. The code will be like:

```
    echo '<td><input type=text style=width:100px name=itembrand value="' . htmlspecialchars($itembrand) . ' " </td>';
    echo '<td><input type=text style=width:150px name=itemname value="' . htmlspecialchars($itemname) . '" </td>';
    echo '<td><input type=text style=width:150 name=serialnr value="' . htmlspecialchars($serialnr) . '" </td>';
    echo '<td><input type=text style=width:150px name=addinfo value="' . htmlspecialchars($addinfo) . '" </td><td>';
```

Comment: you should have to try this before posting your question.